# Unknown song from Gakkou Gurashi

Tags: gakkou-gurashi

There is background music in several Gakkou Gurashi episodes that I can't find no matter how hard I look for them.

It's a very peaceful song, no vocals, that's played with a synthesizer at first and plays into a guitar. It's present usually when the group or character is discussing something peacefully, or in the quiet before the storm in the later episodes.

The most notable placement I can think of is Episode 3 when Megu-Nee is getting ready for the day. It starts around when she opens her message box on her phone, and ends right before the scene ends when she checks her watch.

If anyone can help me with this, I'd be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same track as you when I heard it on air! The music was composed by MOSAIC.WAV and the [OST](http://vgmdb.net/album/53825) was finally released a few weeks ago.
The track you're looking for is no. 15: [優しいめぐねえありがとう (Yasashii Megu-nee Arigatou)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7Z6xEGxnVg)

There are a few other tracks I wish made it on, but they're going to release a [2nd volume](http://vgmdb.net/album/54874) on November 26.